# Missing service in `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services`

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-keyspaces

Trying to query public parameters in AWS SSM, I see that Amazon Keyspaces (for Apache Cassandra) is missing from the value of `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services` and `/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/us-east-1/services`.

I query these params both using the Go SDK and the AWS CLI, e.g.:

```
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/global-infrastructure/regions/us-east-1/services"
aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/global-infrastructure/services"
```

I do get a valid response, but Amazon Keyspaces is not there.